# Umbraco upload to Vimeo

Tags: umbraco, vimeo, umbraco6, vimeo-api, umbraco-ucommerce

Maybe someone knows the best way how to use Vimeo API from Umbraco admin pages?
My goal is to upload videos from admin file system directly to Vimeo server.
I'm in investigation mode so I appreciate every suggestion.
I'm working with Umbraco 6.1.6 + uCommerce

Answer (score 0):

You could either create create a dashboard user control, a custom admin section or perhaps use the Media Library (I'd create a new media type first for Vimeo items with the appropriate properties) and hook into the Umbraco API for events.

I'd personally go with the latter if possible - it keeps the content manageable within Umbraco and can easily used across the rest of the site.

http://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Reference/Events-v6/MediaService-Events

Here's a rough example of using the Umbraco Media API w/ PDF files

http://www.web-garden.co.uk/blog/2013/4/18/generating-thumbnail-images-for-pdfs-in-umbraco

Here's an example of extending Umbraco with a Admin section / Tree if you want to roll your own interface / uploading logic

http://blog.sitereactor.dk/2009/04/26/google-analytics-for-umbraco-first-installment/